# selector not sent by methodSignatureForSelector to forwardInvocation

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to change which method is called on an object for the sake of learning.
Here is my code.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A : NSObject
-(void) say: (NSString*) s;
-(NSMethodSignature*) methodSignatureForSelector: (SEL) aSelector;
-(void) forwardInvocation: (NSInvocation*) invocation;
@end

@implementation A
-(void) say: (NSString*) s {
  printf( "say \"%s\"", [s UTF8String] );
}
-(NSMethodSignature*) methodSignatureForSelector: (SEL) aSelector {
  return [A instanceMethodSignatureForSelector: @selector(say:)];
}
-(void) forwardInvocation: (NSInvocation*) invocation {
  // [invocation setSelector:@selector(say:)];
  [invocation invokeWithTarget:self];
}
@end

int main(int args, char* argv[]){
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  A* myObject = [[[A alloc] init] autorelease];

  [myObject tryToSay:@"Hello strange method!"];

  [pool release];
  return 0;
}
```

I want to use -say: no matter which method is attempted used on objects of the class A.

The result is a Segfault.
It seems the invocation object sent to forwardInvocation still has @selector(tryToSay:) as its selector. Is it not supposed to get the same selector that was set in methodSignatureForSelector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not. `NSMethodSignature` doesn't encode the selector. It encodes the signature of the method instead. This means things like the type and number of arguments. It's also not going to work correctly. If someone tries to invoke a method like `-setInteger:` which takes an NSUInteger, it will be passed to your method `-say:` which is expecting an `NSString*`. But it won't get an `NSString*`, it will get an `NSUInteger`, and any attempt to dereference that will crash (unless it's 0).

Comment: Then I guess I don't understand why it is so important to override `-methodSignatureForSelector:`. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you don't provide a method signature, and the runtime can't find a method with that selector itself, then it cannot construct the `NSInvocation` to begin with. The reason why my example causes a crash despite the method signature is that both `NSUInteger` and `NSString*` get passed into a function the same way (e.g. registers/stack). The problem is if you pass `3` in, your resulting `-say:` will try to treat `3` as an object pointer, and when dereferenced it will crash.